# Combining a Date and a Time Column into One Timestamp Column

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I create a timestamp column from a date and a time column in Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

Oracle databases have a date data type (which contains date and time down the second) and several timestamp data types (which have date date and time with subsecond granularity - up to 9 digits).
There are two interval data types (year to month and day to second).
There is no time data type.

Answer (score 0):

And in addition to Chip's explanation, you can create a timestamp by using the [TO_TIMESTAMP function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions213.htm#SQLRF06142)

Regards,
Rob.